# Autumn season challenge

Tags: temple-run-2

How do I finish autumn season challenge in temple run 2? I have collected more than 75000 coins as required, but I still could not claim the golden pumpkin. Also it continuously tells me to "Finish a global challenge".

Answer (score 2):

The challenge isn't over until it's over for everyone. Then you'll be able to finish the challenge and collect your reward.